# how to start countdown

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

any ideas for making this work?

I started to make a countdown for some tasks in a job boards i am making, but the code doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated :)

```
<div data-bind="value: function llogarit(due_date){
  var data = due_date;
var countDownDate = new Date(data).getTime(),
    countdownfunction = setInterval(function() {
        var e = (new Date).getTime(),
            n = countDownDate - e,
            t = Math.floor(n / 864e5),
            o = Math.floor(n % 864e5 / 36e5),
            a = Math.floor(n % 36e5 / 6e4),
            r = Math.floor(n % 6e4 / 1e3); 
    console.log(e);
    }  ">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've tagged *knockoutjs*, I'll focus on the knockout errors:

- You're using the `value` binding on a `<div>`, which is not supported. Use the `text` binding instead.
- The javascript passed to the binding has a syntax error, causing the binding's `init` method to throw an error.
- The function you pass does not `return` anything, so knockout will not be able to inject any HTML.
- The passed javascript does not contain any `observable` value, so knockout will not have a mechanism to keep things up to date.

My proposal to fix these issues, putting the logic neatly inside a viewmodel:

```js
// Ticker returns an observable time integer
// that is updated on a fixed `interval`
var Ticker = function(interval) {
  var obsNow = ko.observable(Date.now());

  setInterval(
    function() {
      obsNow(Date.now());
    },
    interval
  );

  return obsNow;
};

var CountDown = function(to) {
  // CountDown creates its own ticker that triggers
  // an update every 1000ms
  // Note: if you plan to dispose the instance, make
  //       sure you implement a disposal mechanism
  //       for the ticker as well
  var currentTime = Ticker(1000);

  // Counter formats a time difference in to a neat string
  // that can be used in your view
  this.counter = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    // By referencing the observable time integer,
    // we ensure automatic updates
    var e = currentTime(),
      n = to - e,
      t = Math.floor(n / 864e5),
      o = Math.floor(n % 864e5 / 36e5),
      a = Math.floor(n % 36e5 / 6e4),
      r = Math.floor(n % 6e4 / 1e3);

    // Note: this logic might better be defined in
    //       several steps, or even in the view.
    return t + "d, " + [o, a, r].map(l2).join(":");
  });
};

// Count down to 2 days from now
ko.applyBindings(new CountDown(Date.now() + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

// Left pad numbers to a min. length of 2 (1 -> "01")
function l2(x) {
  return (x < 10 ? "0" : "") + x;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="text: counter"></div>
```

Comment: We want to use the due_date var that we get from app.js with post,how to use that and than call it.problem also is the mvc ,we can put everything in one file

Comment: You *could* use `<div data-bind="text: (new CountDown(due_date)).counter"></div>` but I wouldn't recommend it. Have a look at [components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html) and [custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) instead.

Comment: the only prb is ko is undefined  when we already have included that in our header..

Comment: I'm afraid I can't come up with an answer that uses a *knockout data-bind*, but does **not** reference `ko` and **cannot** include additional javascript outside of the `data-bind` attribute... Can you not add the code I provided above `ko.applyBindings` in `app.js`?

Comment: we do not add it in app.js we add it directly in the view ,if we add it in the app.js we have to make a call,we will try even that and let you know

Comment: it shows-: Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript not code you have above does not seem to be complete:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var e = (new Date).getTime(),
        n = countDownDate - e,
        t = Math.floor(n / 864e5),
        o = Math.floor(n % 864e5 / 36e5),
        a = Math.floor(n % 36e5 / 6e4),
        r = Math.floor(n % 6e4 / 1e3);
    console.log(e);
}
```

is actually missing the `milliseconds` parameters.

See [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) for the documentation of the setInterval function.

Most likely this will be syntactically correct:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var e = (new Date).getTime(),
        n = countDownDate - e,
        t = Math.floor(n / 864e5),
        o = Math.floor(n % 864e5 / 36e5),
        a = Math.floor(n % 36e5 / 6e4),
        r = Math.floor(n % 6e4 / 1e3);
    console.log(e);
}, 3000);
```

Comment: it shows-: Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element